# Javascript or jQuery form validation only for exact action

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, action

I have a form with several action buttons, and every button has a different action.
For example, one button is "Save and continue" and another is "Save and finished". I want to validate values from selections on the form, and if the value is equаl to some number, only then can it run the action "finished". I want to validate only for this exact action.

I try this but it did not work:

```
function OnSubmitForm() { 
    if(document.pressed == 'SOME ACTION') { 
       var x=document.forms["FORM NAME"]["INPUT NAME"].value; 
       var i=""; 
       if (x==null || x!=i) { 
           alert("You can't do this"); 
           return false; 
       } 
    } 
    else 
       return true; 
}
```

My idea is to validate only when clicking on the exact action on the form.

Comment: Sounds like a great project. So, what's your question?

Comment: Please edit the code into your question.

Comment: I can't put the code. Something wrong I put the code in ``

Comment: I try this but don't work:

`function OnSubmitForm()
{
  if(document.pressed == 'SOME ACTION')
  {
 var x=document.forms["FORM NAME"]["INPUT NAME"].value;
 var i="<?php echo $sum; ?>";
 if (x==null || x!=i)
   {
   alert("You can't do this");
   return false;
   }
  }
 else
   return true;
}`

Comment: I have in my form 2 buttons, I want to make validation only if click one of the buttons. The buttons are with different actions and I don't want all form validation, only for exact action for the form.

Comment: <input name="action" type="submit" value="Save">
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Finished" onClick="document.pressed=this.value">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I have an idea. Why don't you listen for the `change` event on your `<select>` element and update the buttons `disabled` attribute, like so.

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function() {
    var value = this.value,
        disabled = null;
    if( value === 1 ) {
        disabled = true;
    } else if( value === 2 ) {
        disabled = false;
    } 
    $('#theButton').prop('disabled', disabled);
});
```

Or if you want to do it the *nerdy* way you could do this.

```
$('#mySelectBox').change(function() {
    var value = this.value,
        disabled = value === 1 ? true : false;
    $('#theButton').prop('disabled', disabled);
});
```

That should work, hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying your way right now, I'll say in 10 min what's happend. I like the idea to be disabled the button :)

Comment: It's done with  onChange="function=this.value" THANKS VERY MUCH :)